# How to run a process that have an argument containing new-lines?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, quoting

I have a command that have the structure :
`xrdcp "root://server/file?authz=ENVELOPE&Param1=Val1" local_file_path`
The problem is that ENVELOPE in text that should be unquoted in command line
and it contains a lot of new-lines
I cannot use repr as it will replace new-line with \n
Moreover subprocess seems to automatically use repr on the items from the list arguments

In bash this command is usually run with
`xrdcp "root://server/file?authz=$(<ENVELOPE)&Param1=Val1" local_file`

So, is there a way to run a command while keeping the new lines in the arguments?
Thank you!

Later Edit:
my actual code is :

```
envelope = server['envelope']
complete_url = "\"" + server['url'] + "?" + "authz=" + "{}".format(server['envelope']) + xrdcp_args + "\""
xrd_copy_list = []
xrd_copy_list.extend(xrdcp_cmd_list)
xrd_copy_list.append(complete_url)
xrd_copy_list.append(dst_final_path_str)
xrd_job = subprocess.Popen(xrd_copy_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = xrd_job.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it converts the new-lines"? `\n` _is_ a new-line character. What is being converted to what, exactly? I wonder if you need is to percent-quote your url, so that the newlines _are_ converted. Try something like `envelope = urllib.parse.quote(server['envelope'])`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please include exactly what you expect the command line to look like and exactly what `server['envelope']` looks like (with any sensitive information redacted, of course).

Comment: i meant that the new-lines are converted to literal "\n" and in that it change the string that is sent to the server in the url. i will look into urllib.parse.quote, thanks a lot!

Comment: so, i did a workaround : i created a metalink fille with urls specified with CDATA and i could use metalink for downloading the files. in the metalink i just used write({}.format(url))